# Find all kinds of numbers within a string

Tags: c#, string, numbers, replace

The string can contains ints, floats and hexadecimal numbers for example.

"This a string than can have -345 and 57 and could also have 35.4656 or a subtle 0xF46434 and more"

What could I use to find these numbers in C#?

Comment: You first need to define "number". For example are numbers always delimited by spaces?

Comment: @MrLister: Sorry, Numbers could have a semicolon(;) after them! Also any words like int2ger should be ignored!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something along these lines: (I wrote it myself, so I'm not going to say it's all-inclusive for whatever sort of numbers you're looking to find, but it works for your example)

```
var str = "123 This a string than can have -345 and 57 and could also have 35.4656 or a subtle 0XF46434 and more like -0xf46434";
var a = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_^]))(-?\d+(\.\d+)?|-?0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+)(?=([^a-zA-Z0-9_]|$))");
foreach (Match match in a)
{
    //do something
}
```

Regex seems to be a write-only language, (i.e. incredibly hard to read) so I'll break it down so you can understand: `(?<=(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_^]))` is a lookbehind to break it by a word boundary.  I can't use `\b` because it considers `-` a boundary character, so it would only match `345` instead of `-345`.  `-?\d+(\.\d+)?` matches decimal numbers, optionally negative, optionally with fractional digits.  `-?0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+` matches hexadecimal numbers, case insensitive, optionally negative.  Finally, `(?=([^a-zA-Z0-9_]|$))` is a lookahead, again as a word boundary.  Note that in the first boundary, I allowed for the start of the string, and here I allow for the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to parse each word to `double` and `return` the `array` of `double`s.

Here is a way to get `array` of `double`s from a `string`:

```
double[] GetNumbers(string str)
{
    double num;
    List<double> l = new List<double>();
    foreach (string s in str.Split(' '))
    {
        bool isNum = double.TryParse(s, out num);
        if (isNum)
        {
            l.Add(num);
        }
    }
    return l.ToArray();
}
```

more info about `double.TryParse()` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx).

Comment: `return l.ToArray()` will be better!

Comment: Could this also find ints and negative numbers and hexadecimal numbers?

Comment: @KevinBoyd - yes, please have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx

Comment: I dont know if it will work faster or slower than the regex provided by others, but it sure is much more readable and clean solution. nice one

Comment: From `Double.TryParse` doc: "The following NumberStyles members are not supported:

NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier

NumberStyles.HexNumber".  Add this before `if (isNum)`:                 `if (!isNum && s.IndexOf("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        num = Convert.ToInt64(s, 16);
                        isNum = true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        isNum = false;
                    }
                }`

Comment: Note that my code here will only detect positive hex numbers.  It also really detracts from the simplicity of your method.  Unfortunately, it's necessary when using this approach of split + parse.

Answer (score 1):

Given your input above this expression matches every number present there

```
string line = "This a string than can have " + 
                      "-345 and 57 and could also have 35.4656 " +
                      "or a subtle 0xF46434 and more";

Regex r = new Regex(@"(-?0[Xx][A-Fa-f0-9]+|-?\d+\.\d+|-?\d+)");
var m = r.Matches(line);
foreach(Match h in m)
    Console.WriteLine(h.ToString());
```

EDIT: for a replace you use the Replace method that takes a MatchEvaluator overload

```
string result = r.Replace(line, new MatchEvaluator(replacementMethod));
public string replacementMethod(Match match)
{
   return "?????";
}
```

Explaining the regex pattern

First, the sequence `"(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)"` means that we have three possible pattern to find in our string. One of them is enough to have a match

First pattern `-?0[Xx][A-Fa-f0-9]+` means an optional minus followed by a zero followed by an X or x char followed by a series of one or more chars in the range A-F a-f or 0-9

Second pattern `-?\d+\.\d+` means an optional minus followed by a series of 1 or more digits followed by the decimal point followed by a series of 1 or more digits

Third pattern `-?\d+` means an optional minus followed by a series of 1 or more digits.

The sequence of patterns is of utmost importance. If you reverse the pattern and put the integer match before the decimal pattern the results will be wrong.

Comment: if I want to do a replace in the foreach what do I use there?

Comment: OK, updated the pattern to take also negative decimal numbers in account

Comment: Fantastic! Sorry! I already awarded Tim S. for the right answer

Comment: Your regex expression also looks smaller than Tim S. How did you achieve it? Also If I need to do a replace per match in the for each loop do I need to do something different?

Comment: @KevinBoyd Yes it is smaller, but something in the solution from Tim S. is better. My answer don't recognize if a number is embedded inside a word. Like `TimSolution123isbetter`. I will get that 123 as a match. For the replace you don't need a foreach. The replacementMethod will be called one time for each match. Examine the Match properties to decide what to do inside the replacement method.

Comment: Thanks Steve! Wish I could have 2 selected answers!!

Answer (score 1):

Besides regex, which tends to have its own problems, you can build a state machine to do the processing. You can decide on which inputs the machine would accept as 'numbers'. Unlike regex, a state machine will have predictably decent performance, and will also give you predictable results (whereas regex can sometimes match rather surprising things).

It's not really that difficult, when you think about it. There are rather few states, and you can define special cases explicitly.

EDIT: The following is an edit as a response to the comment.
In .NET, Regex is implemented as an [NFA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k) (Nontdeterminisitc Finite Automaton). On one hand, it's a very powerful parser, but on the other, it can sometimes [backtrack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045.aspx) much more than it should. This is especially true when you're accepting unsafe input (input from the user, which can be just about anything). While I'm not sure what sort of Regex expression you'll be using to parse the result, you can induce a performance hit in pretty much anything. Although in most cases performance is a non-issue, Regex performance can scale exponentially with the input. That means that, in some cases, it really *can* be a bottleneck. And a rather unexpected one.

Another potential problem stemming from the greedy nature of Regex is that sometimes it can match unexpected things. You might use the same Regex expression for days, and it might work fine, waiting for the right combination of overlooked characters to be parsed, and you'll end up writing garbage into your database.

---

By state machine, I mean parsing the input using a deterministic finite automaton, or something like that. I'll show you what I mean. Here's a small [DFA](http://goo.gl/1guLB) for parsing a positive decimal integer or float within a string. I'm pretty sure you can build a DFA using frameworks like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html), though I'm sure there are also less powerful ones around.

Comment: Greg, 1) what are the problems associated with regex. 2) Could you provide an example for the state machine, its difficult for me to visualize what you trying to get across?